# System.FormatException after update donet and ef core

Tags: c#, string, datetime, exception, format

I got this strange error out of a sudden after updating from dotnet 6.0 to dotnet 7.0
and EF CORE from Version 12 to Version 13.
But even more strange is; if i debug it in my meshine, it works.
if i run this in a docker container on my synology NAS, i get this problem.
But it worked before the update.

Input:

```
<td>23.01.2023 16:20:58</td>
```

try to parse like this

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(columns[0].InnerHtml, new CultureInfo("de-DE")),
Time = Convert.ToDateTime(columns[0].InnerHtml, new CultureInfo("de-DE")).TimeOfDay
```

the actual error i got is:

```
System.FormatException: String '23.01.2023 16:20:58' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
```

what could going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you think the culture identifier of that file is (you seem to think it's German?), there is exactly one way to correctly parse a date from a string when you know what format it is: `DateTime.[Try]ParseExact`.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23.01.2023 16:20:58", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)
```